# aggregating values typeorm

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

Given a list of tasks that contain subtasks (one task to many subtasks)
I would like to query tasks by `task.is_complete` (meaning all `task.subtasks.complete` are `true`)

What would be the suggested approach in terms of performance?

I was looking at https://typeorm.io/listeners-and-subscribers but did not find a use case where update in one entity updates another entity so I am not sure it is the right way to implement.

Comment: After researching there are a few suggested solutions (until the official support for addSelectAndMap will be implemented), 
https://pietrzakadrian.com/blog/virtual-column-solutions-for-typeorm
I chose the simple one as described by one of the creators of TypeORM:
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1822#issuecomment-380552203